# Reveal.js navigation doesn't work within a jquery click event

Tags: jquery, reveal.js

I hope anyone is familiar with [Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) it's an amazing presentation/slide.
Its, really simple but with my jQuery Navigation function the [Links](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#internal-links) won't work.
If I remove the jQuery function the slide sections are called properly.

What am I missing?

```
navigation: function () {

var $items;
items = $('.items a.see-all');
items.on('click', function (e) {


e.preventDefault(); 

$('.wrap-content').css({
     opacity: 0,
    'z-index': -1
  });
$('.wrap-section').css({
     opacity: 1,
     'z-index': 1
   }); 
});

},
```

Comment: Any fiddle to see what you have till now? http://jsbin.com

Comment: @Sunny R Gupta I'm trying to put it together

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/61/

Comment: @Sunny R Gupta could you please have a look this?

Comment: It is working I guess?

Comment: What is expected behavior. When the page loads, should the presentation be displayed? If no, should it load after any one of one, two, three is clicked?

Comment: Was this problem happening on all browser types? or just a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Check it :

```
navigation: function () {

$('.items a.see-all').on('click', function (e) {


e.preventDefault(); 

$('.wrap-content').css({
     'opacity': 0,
    'z-index': -1
  });
$('.wrap-section').css({
     'opacity': 1,
     'z-index': 1
   }); 
});

},
```